# File Permissions for /opt

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I was installing xampp on my ubuntu watching this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsDnUpCUGPM" , youtube video.
One of the steps to enable oracle extension of php asked to write the following commands:
"sudo su" , 
"sudo chmod 777 -R  /opt/lampp"

Then it asked to go to the etc folder and do the following:

"In php.ini remove (;) from the line ;zend_extension=opcache.so"

After this the phpmyadmin link is not working.[This is what is shows after clicking on phpmyadmin on localhost/dashboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy41y.png)

I think i have messed up the permissions. Please help so that it doesn't affect my other work.

Comment: "sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp" No. That is never the correct answer. opt should be owned by root. Permissions should always already be correct when extracting the installer (that's the whole idea of the tar install).  From the installer there should also be a config file where you set a user and password that are used for that service

Comment: please return the file to `sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp` not sure what the original permissions were...

Comment: Oh and ditch xampp. Our native lampp is easier to install, more secure and production ready. And take some time to invest in python and perl. If you want to be my friend ... friends should not let their friends to use php :+)